# Row reduced $2\times3$ echelon matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $R$ and $R'$ are two $2\times3$ row reduced echelon matrices if  $RX=0$ and  $R'X$ have axactly same solutions then prove that
 $R=R'$.

My try:

Let $x,y,z$ be the same solution of $R$ and $R'$
The most general form of $R$ will be
$$R=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & b\\
0 & 1 & c\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ 
Similarly
$$R'=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & p & q\\
0 & 1 & r\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Using given Condition we have
$$x+ay+bz=0,\\ 
y+cz=0$$
Now this system has one free variable...
For $R'$ will give similar equations but the trouble is free variable

Comment: The way I define reduced row-echelon form, it has to be $$\pmatrix{1&0&a\cr0&1&b\cr}$$

Comment: thanks Sir, that is where i made an error.

Answer (score 2):

I think, this is not true for matrices in row ecelon form. Consider $R=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $R'=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$

EDIT: For matrix in a reduced row echelon form, i.e. 
$R=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&a\\0&1&b\end{pmatrix}$ and 
$R=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&p\\0&1&q\end{pmatrix}$
compare the lines in $yz$ space from the first equation 
$$y+bz=0$$ and from the second equation $$y+qz=0.$$ The lines defined by these equations equal and you can easily conclude $b=q$. You can then continue in a similar way with the first line.

Comment: This question is in Exercise 3 page no 16 Q 10 of Keneth Hoffman Ray Kunze.
we have to Prove that matrices are equal given that solutions are same. So if you want to disprove it you have to suggest a solution for which matrices are not equal not the converse. Sir , I am a begginer, I may be wrong.

Comment: Perhaps the matrices should be in a reduced(!) row echelon form. Then it is true. So $p=a=0$ in your notation and my counterexample does not apply.

Comment: I have already mentioned that in Question, but yes I have made a wrong attempt.

Comment: Now I got the sol. thanku sir.